# Slow fall in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Unity project, but when I apply the Animator Controller my PJ falls very slow, Root Motion in Animator is disabled and I do not see any property in Animations...

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9oE1.png)

Comment: It is hard to say the reason with the information provided. You should add more details about what is going on. Has the PJ any script attached? The other objects in the scene has the same behaviour? this slow fall started just after you applied the animator?

Comment: Is the problem a slow animation or that by adding an animation the physics are now behaving strangely (slow falling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this using a script. Here's a c# example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Animation anim;

   void Start()
   {
      // Walk backwards
      anim["Walk"].speed = -1.0f;

      // Walk at double speed
      anim["Walk"].speed = 2.0f;
   }
}
```

Just point to the animator you are using and place the name of the animation in quotes ["example"]. Negative values play the animation in reverse and positives values speed up the animation as they are increased.

Hope it helps

Comment: But this script is to modify the speed of the animation just, isn't? As I understand the problem is the object falls down slowly... So you consider the animation is just the Pj falling down?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I have misunderstood the problem. I thought he was stating that he had a fall animation but it was running slowly. Not that adding the animator was messing with the physics in the game (which would be weird). I'll ask for more info :)